# ¿Porque al pegar del portapapeles aparece como si no existiera?

Tags: excel, vba

Coloque una macro en mi codigo que me ayudara a copiar mas rapido un texto de un textbox para simplemente pegarla en un chat de whatsapp por ejemplo,
al principio me funciono pero luego ya no, le doy a copiar y no me copia el mensaje, sino que me aparece estos simbolos , cuando reviso el portapapeles de excel me aparece que el texto se copio, pero cuando intento pegarlo me aparecen los simbos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Private Sub COPIAR_PP_Click()

```
Dim PP As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim texto1 As String

If TXT_MENSAJE.Text <> Empty Then

    texto1 = CStr(TXT_MENSAJE.Text)
    Set PP = New DataObject
    PP.SetText texto1
    PP.PutInClipboard

End If
```

End sub

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se está documentando un error en Windows 10 con este tema. Al parecer, si tienes abierto el explorador de archivos con anterioridad a excel, simplemente no funcionará, sin embargo, si abres excel, y después el explorador, no tendrás problema.
(NO he podido comprobarlo, pero quizá tú que tienes la rutina funcionando podrías hacerlo e indicarnos si te funcionó)
En [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134654/vba-settext-and-putinclipboard-putting-two-symbols-in-clipboard-instead-of-des), [@Bill Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16047744/bill-simpson) hizo un arreglo que funcionó para él. Quizá te sirva.